# How to use XML namespaces with xmlstarlet XPaths?

Tags: xml, xpath, element, edit, xmlstarlet

at the moment I am struggeling editing a XML file. When I write the command

```
xml ed -u "/project/version" -v "2.7.13-NEW-SNAPSHOT" pom.xml > ./pom_new.xml
```

it writes the new xml file, but when I open the file nothings changed in it.

Heres a part of the given xml, i want to edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.groupID.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-api-parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.13-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>test-api-parent-pom</name>
    ...
    ...
</project>
```

Any ideas on that?

Comment: See [Chapter 5, Section 1](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05.html) of the user guide.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your xmlstarlet command will work if you take account of your document's namespace using `-N p=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0`:

```
xml ed -N p=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 -u "/p:project/p:version" -v "2.7.13-NEW-SNAPSHOT" pom.xml > ./pom_new.xml
```

### Reference links

- [XmlStarlet Command Line XML Toolkit User's Guide](https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/index.html)

  - [Chapter 5. Common problems](https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05.html)

    - [1. Namespaces and default namespace](https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05.html)

Comment: Wow... worked like a charm. You really made my day. Thank you.